# Are non-abelian torsion free groups, totally ordered?

Tags: group-theory

It is well-known that abelian torsion-free groups are totally ordered?
Is this the case for all torsion-free groups in general?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81103/left-orderable-linear-groups

Comment: You'd better specified what you mean by totally ordered. Anyway, nonabelian free groups admit bi-invariant total orderings.